# Swap first two letters of every word in string

Tags: php, string, swap, cpu-word, word-boundary

I have a string:

```
Hello, How Are You.
```

I want this output:

```
eHllo, oHw rAe oYu.
```

It doesn't matter whether there are any special characters, I just want to reverse the first two letters in every word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` like as

```
$str = "Hello, How Are You.";
echo preg_replace_callback("/([a-z]+)/i",function($m){
    return implode(array_map('strrev',str_split($m[0],2)));
},$str);
```

Output:

```
eHllo, oHw rAe oYu.
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/uS5QE)

Answer (score 0):

It is overkill to use `preg_replace_callback() because a pattern with two capture groups affords the simpler call of` preg_replace()`.

Use `\b` (word boundary) to identify the start of a word.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cns25))

```
$str = "Hello, How Are You.";
echo preg_replace(
         '/\b([a-z])([a-z])/i',
         '$2$1',
         $str
     );
// eHllo, oHw rAe oYu.
```